# Reach for the nested element using Selenium WebDriver (Java)

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, pdf-viewer

I want to click the 'Download' button on the pdf-viewer page using Selenium. This is html code of that page.
[image]

I suppose I need to use `switchTo().frame()` to reach for the element marked with red frame. I use the following Java code for that.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='viewer']")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toolbar']")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='downloads']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='download']")).click();
```

But it doesn't work :( Please, give me some ideas how to solve the problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As per the screen shot, the Element is in a `shadow-root` with `Mode` `open`.

To get the required element inside the `shadow DOM`, we need to make use of `Javascript`.

You can refer [This Link](https://cosmocode.io/how-to-interact-with-shadow-dom-in-selenium) about interacting with `Shadom DOM`

The code would be something like this:

```
public class shadowdomexample {
    
    WebElement root1 = driver.findElement(By.id("viewer"));

    //Get shadow root element
    WebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);
    
    WebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.id("toolbar"));
    WebElement shadowRoot2 = expandRootElement(root2);
    
    WebElement root3 = shadowRoot2.findElement(By.id("downloads"));
    WebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(root3);
    
    //This should return the required Element.
    WebElement DownloadsElement = shadowRoot3.findElement(By.cssSelector("cr-icon-button[id=downloads]"));

}
//Returns webelement
public WebElement expandRootElement(WebElement element) {
    WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",element);
    return ele;
}
```

Comment: The link you shared is about this particular case. I tried the code suggested by you and played with the suggestions mentioned in that article but all these options didn't work. The problem is even to get an access to the first shadow DOM. The result - exception: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='viewer']"

Comment: Can you share the Link I mean URL?

Comment: And also have you tried finding element inside a `shadow root` with CSS selector. Try to find `downloads ` using CSS selector.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. This web-site is for internal use only :( I tried using css. The same problem - no such element: Unable to locate element.

Comment: Its a nested shadow root. Refer this link once - https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver

Comment: @Shubt - Have updated the code. Do try once.

Comment: Thank you for your time! But still I catch no such element exception... I've got an idea how to solve my problem in other manner. Now I'm investigating how to disable chrome pdf-viewer extension to download the file directly. I'm almost there

Comment: Well anyway, post your answer so that it would be helpful for others.